# My website is hacked and injected

Tags: php, injection

Someone hacked into my website, injected the source code and somehow is able to delete application files remotely 
What are the best practices to better secure the website, its an e-commerce website soon to start receiving sales and payment 
Im panicked, i dont know what to do

Comment: We are very sorry this happened to you and it is frustrating. Unfortunately, we cannot possibly cover all the things you need to do to better secure your website. Such a broad question would require many books worth of answers. If you have a specific question about a specific thing about your site, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thats the issue i dont know what to start with, but is it possible to clean the website from the injections ? If I hire someone can he/she get everything back normal

Comment: The duplicate that I linked to provides multiple options for how to handle the infection.